# TextInputLayout with AutoCompleteTextView not showing full text of item

Tags: java, android, autocompletetextview, material-components-android, android-textinputlayout

I'm using com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout with style Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox.ExposedDropdownMenu and using also AutoCompleteTextView. These make the input as dropdown list. But the issue right now is long text of list won't show the complete item text. How can I show all the text and make it multiline?

```
 <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    style="@style/CustomStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/label_input">

     <AutoCompleteTextView
       android:id="@+id/autocomplete"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:inputType="text"
       android:inputType="none" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

themes.xml

```
<style name="LayoutDropdown" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox.ExposedDropdownMenu">
   <item name="boxBackgroundColor">@color/white</item>
   <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
   <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/black</item>
   <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/black</item>
   <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/black</item>
</style>
```

Java

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.dropdown_menu_item, list);
AutoCompleteTextView dropdown = findViewById(R.id.autocomplete);
dropdown.setAdapter(adapter);
dropdown.setKeyListener(null);
```

dropdown_menu_item.xml

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceSubtitle1"/>
```

Here is the result. It doesn't show full text on selection dropdown.

[image]

Comment: Add the code you are using to set the adapter

Comment: @AgentP ok. edited the question

Comment: Have you created dropdown_menu_item.xml ? if so please add that also

Comment: @AgentP Updated the question.

Comment: You've specified `maxLines` to be 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the layout used for each item.
Use something like:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.dropdown_menu_item,R.id.item, list);
```

with:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ...
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Also if you want to display the long text also in the `AutoCompleteTextView` use `android:inputType="textMultiLine"`

```
  <com.google.android.material.textfield.MaterialAutoCompleteTextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                     />
```

[image]